# Converting a list of dicts to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of Python `dict`s each with the same keys,

```
dict_keys= ['k1','k2','k3','k4','k5','k6'] # More like 30 keys in practice
data = []
for i in range(20): # More like 3000 in practice
    data.append({k: np.random.randint(100) for k in dict_keys})
```

and would like to use it to create a corresponding Pandas dataframe with a subset of the keys. My current approach is to take each `dict` from the list one at a time and append it to the dataframe using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['k1','k2','k5','k6'])
for d in data:
    df = df.append({k: d[k] for k in list(df.columns)}, ignore_index=True)
    # In practice, there are some calculations on some of the values here
```

but this is *very slow* (the actual list, and the dicts it contains, are both quite large).

Is there a better, faster (and more idiomatic) method for iterating through a list of dictionaries and adding them as rows to a Pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply pass `data` to `DataFrame`'s `__init__`, or to [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) (either would work).

You might also want to set an index, e.g. `DataFrame.from_records(data, index = 'k1')`.

If you need to also perform some calculations, it's usually easier and more convenient to do it on the `DataFrame`, after creating it. Leverage pandas!

Comment: Wow, `from_records` is *fast*!